# Someone else said exactly the same thing before you could say

Tags: phrase-request

Is there a phrase for this 
You wanted to say something, but Someone else said exactly the same thing before you could say ( you feel like they stole the exact words you wanted to say) 
How do I describe this feeling ? I came across a phrase "beat to the punch" , but I don't think this phrase fits here

Answer (score 4):

As *Teacher KSHuang* mentioned in the comments, **[take the words out of somebody's mouth](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/take-the-words-out-of-sb-s-mouth)** is a very common idiomatic expression meaning *to say something that another person was just about to say or was thinking.* The usage generally follows the pattern of *"(you) took the words right out of my mouth"*. For example:

> A: "This movie is going to put me to sleep."
>
> B (yawning): "You took the words right out of my mouth."

or

> A: "What a rude and obnoxious man!"
>
> B: "You took the words right out of my mouth!"

To **beat somebody to the punch**, on the other hand, usually refers to the physical act of *doing* something before someone else does it, rather than just speaking.

> I wanted to post an answer, but someone beat me to the punch.
>
> I was planning to take care of the problem for him, but he beat me to the punch and did it himself.

Answer (score -2):

You feel, "upstaged".

One way to describe the feeling might be to express, "They stole my thunder".

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well. See the [Submitting Answers that merely answer the question](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1117) discussion on meta.